# Getting "There is no connectivity" when trying to manage an FSxN File System within BlueXP

Tags: netapp, amazon-fsx

I added a FSxN file system to my BlueXP canvas a few weeks ago and it was working perfectly until yesterday. Now, when I try to "enter it" I am presented with a "There is no connectivity" error page.

[image]

I have confirmed that I can access the FSxN from the connector over both ports 22 and 443, so I don't think it is actually a connectivity problem. Regardless. I checked the Security Group and ACL rules and I'm not seeing anything that would hinder traffic flowing between the two systems.

If anyone has any ideas as to what else could be causing the problem, and/or where to look to diagnose the issue, I'd appreciate hearing them.

Comment: Can you log into the connector to look at log files?

Comment: Yes, where should look?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have to just put that in my first comment. Look in /opt/application/netapp/cloudmanager/docker_occm/data/log. For connector to FSxN communication, look at debug.ontap.log. Look towards the bottom and see if you see any tell-tale signs as to what might be the problem. I've seen this before, just trying to confirm before I suggest a fix.

Comment: Yeah, okay, in there are messages like: "{"error":{"code":"6691623", "message":"User is not authorized."}. Is this a permission problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is when BlueXP has bad credentials for the fsxadmin user for the FSxN file system you are trying to manage. The simple fix is to simply remove the FSxN Working Environment from your canvas and add it back. When you do that, BlueXP should prompt you for the current password.

Unfortunately, there is no way to just set the password for an FSxN file system like you can for a CVO. Well, that isn't entirely true, if you bring up your browser's developer's tools when the BlueXP console is prompting you for the password, after you fill in the password and click on “Submit", you will see what API it uses to set the password.

Note that the remove and rediscover method only works if the FSxN file system is only in one workspace. If it is in multiple, you will have to either use the undocumented API mentioned above, or remove it from all the workspaces and then add it back.